# Anyway to pull Sharepoint lists directly with a Java program to extract large amounts of data without first exporting to excel?

Tags: sharepoint-list, data, java

Does anyone know if there is anyway to pull lists from SharePoint directly using a Java program?  I would like my program to automatically pull data from SharePoint every so often that I would set up on my own, however I am running into problems whilst attempting to retrieve the data in the first place to even start to do anything with said data.  Sorry if any of this is vague but my main question is again: is there anyway to pull data with a Java program straight from SharePoint.  Thanks.

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [SharePoint REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service). The documentation has a special section on [how to work with lists and items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest).

Essentially you would call something like `http://site-url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items`

Also there seems to be [JShare](http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare/index.html).